# SPD extraction/save problem

Tags: sharepoint-designer, check-out, check-in, online

My problem is that, in SPD, some files are displayed as checked out (with the green checked symbol); when I right-click them, I can't check them out. Of course. So I open the file in advanced mode to update some code, but when I save, SPD yells at me because I "must check out the file to modify it".

So I go to Sharepoint online and see that no, the file isn't actually checked out. I check it out. And I go back to SPD to save my changes. Alright, I check the file in. SPD still thinks the file is checked out, but well, I don't care if my changes are well updated.

Until yesterday, this worked fine, and I managed to do my things and my saves, but then, the problem went even bigger. Now any changes I make in my file (a .css one in this case, which is located in /Style Library/XYZ/css/) aren't even SAVED, even if the file is checked out. I press Ctrl+S thousands of times, check the file in, re-open the file, and see that none of my changes were saved. Note that the version of the file is correctly incremented, no matter if I check in a minor or major version. From 5.4 it gives me 6.0, then 6.1, etc, but still no changes in the code itself. And the file isn't checked out by anyone else but me.
This is driving me crazy, why does the only tool I have behave this way? I work on an online solution and I can't do anything if SPD forbids me to update some files... any idea on what could cause this? Am I doing something wrong? I always managed my updates the same way, and didn't have any problem until now.

I tried to update another file (.js) which had the same check-in/check-out problem, it is still displayed as checked-out but the changes were saved. But what if it starts to be broken like the other one? Will I have to re-upload every file that Sharepoint doesn't like? They contain no syntax problem, nor do the updates I want to make.

If anyone has/had the same problem, please tell me if there's a way to fix it...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to clear SharePoint designer cache.

To Clear SharePoint Designer Cache **Go to run**(Window + R), and follow below steps:

1) Delete all the files from location

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
```

2) Delete all the files from location

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
```

Reference: http://www.benprins.net/2013/09/03/sharepoint-designer-clearing-the-cache/